# Meteor Server Capture Unhandled Errors

Tags: meteor

I'm currently logging unhandled exceptions on the client by using the `window.onerror` function, like so:

```
window.onerror = function (msg) { //This function logs uncaught errors from the client
    logIt({category:"Client Error",message:msg});
    return false;
};
```

Is there a way to do the same thing on the server side? I'd like to be able to call a function whenever something shows up in the console output.

I've tried `Meteor.onerror`, `Meteor.onError`, and `windows.onError`.

Edit: I still haven't found a way to do it, but I've definitely run into the need this morning even. Any help is appreciated.

I'm reading some places that I can use process.on('uncaughtException'), but I'm also reading others that I can't. It doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: where's a good place to put the `window.onerror` code to catch the client errors?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, although it's not the solution I was hoping for.

With some help from [this file](https://github.com/acemtp/meteor-logentries/blob/master/logentries.js#L26)...

```js
if (Meteor.isServer) {

  var consoleLogOrig = console.log;

  console.log = function(arguments) {
    var msg;
    if (typeof arguments === "string") {
      msg = arguments
    } else {
      msg = arguments[0]
    }

    logIt({
      type: "Server Console",
      message: msg,
      attachment: arguments
    });
    consoleLogOrig.call(console, arguments);
  };


}
```